# Is there any way to generate an ID without a sequence?

Tags: oracle

Current application use JPA to auto generate table/entity id. Now a requirement wants to get a query to manually insert data in to the database using SQL queries

So the questions are:

1. Is it worth to create a sequence in this schema just for this little requirement?
2. If answer to 1 is no, then what could be a plan b?

Comment: Your requirement is a bit vague. *A query to manually insert* doesn't mean much (to me any way). However if you want to generate a sequence of integers based on data you can use ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: @Conrad Frix it is like insert into table(id....) values(someIncrementValue...), so can we use ROW_NUMBER for that `someIncrementValue` ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes.  A sequence is trivial - why would you *not* do it?
2. N/A

Comment: What if the table has existing data that not generated by any sequence ?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I don't understand what you are doing but if you need to generate some unique number then a sequence is the way to do it regardless of how the data you want to associate it with came to be.

Comment: @Dreamer CREATE SEQUENCE has START WITH clause. If the table already has existing data in the ID column and these values are numeric, then you can specify a starting value for the newly created sequence which would be the largest existing value + 1.

Answer (score 3):

Few ways:

1. [Use a UUID](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jpa-implementation-patterns-6). UUIDs are pseudo-random, large alphanumeric strings which are guaranteed to be unique once generated.
2. Does the data have something unique? Like a timestamp, or IP address, etc? If so, use that
3. Combination of current timestamp + some less unique value in the data
4. Combination of current timestamp + some integer `i` that you keep incrementing

There are others (including generating a checksum, custom random numbers instead of UUIDs, etc) - but those have the possibility of overlaps, so not mentioning them.

Edit: Minor clarifications

Answer (score 0):

Are you just doing a single data load into an empty table, and there are no other users concurrently inserting data? If so, you can just use ROWNUM to generate the IDs starting from 1, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT ROWNUM AS ID
      ,etc AS etc
FROM ...
```